# Heap Corruption Detected: after Normal block (#126)

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this Debug Error:

Heap Corruption Detected: after Normal block (#126) at
0x004cF6c0
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap bugger.

I understand that you need to free memory whenever you use new operator,
which I did and I am still getting problems.

for some reason the program doesn't end correctly in the recursive function.
I debugged it and went through each line of code with breakpoints.

At the end of the if statement in countSum it somehow subtracts 1 from i
and then reenters the if block.....which it is not supposed to do.

Why is this occurring?

```
/*this program calculates the sum of all the numbers in the array*/

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

/*prototype*/
void countSum(int, int, int, int*);

int main(){

    bool flag;
    int num;

    int sum = 0, j=0;
    int *array =  new int;

    do{

        system("cls");
        cout<<"Enter a number into an array: ";
        cin>>array[j];

        cout<<"add another?(y/n):";
        char choice;
        cin>>choice;
        choice == 'y' ? flag = true : flag = false;

        j++;

    }while(flag);

    int size = j;

    countSum(sum, 0, size, array);
    //free memory
    delete array;
    array = 0;

    return 0;
}

void countSum(int sum, int i, int size, int *array){

    if (i < size){
        system("cls");

        cout<<"The sum is  :"<<endl;
        sum += array[i];
        cout<<"...."<<sum;

        time_t start_time, stop_time;
        time(&start_time);

        do
        {
            time(&stop_time); //pause for 5 seconds
        }
        while((stop_time - start_time) < 5);

        countSum(sum, (i+1) , size, array); //call recursive function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array` holds enough space for a single `int`:

```
int *array = new int;
```

but there is potentially an attempt to insert more than one `int` which would result in writing to memory that is not available. Either use a [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or it must be known beforehand the maximum number of `int`s that will be entered before `array` is allocated.

If this is a learning exercise and you do not want to use `std::vector<int>` you could prompt the user to enter the number of `int`s they wish to enter:

```
std::cout << "Enter number of integers to be entered: ";
int size = 0;
std::cin >> size;
if (size > 0)
{
    array = new int[size];
}
```

Then accept `size` number of `int`s. Use `delete[]` when you use `new[]`.

Comment: I thought the whole point of creating a dynamic array was so that you could add more.  I never declared the array as const int array[0]

Comment: It means that the size does not need to be known at compile time, but it won't grow automatically: a `std::vector<int>` would.

Comment: yeah I know vectors are better. my teacher of course asked for an array....even though arrays are incredibly annoying and not very helpful when it comes to data.

Comment: can someone explain to me what is the point of a dynamic array? I know it can expand an already allocated array....but that just seems unrealistic because not every scenario is going to have a predetermined number.

Comment: okay. well I got it to work by setting new int[20] ...I still don't understand how dynamic arrays are completely dynamic if you have to set it to a number first. kind of defeats the purpose in some way.

Comment: It allows the size of the array to be determine at runtime, instead of compile time.

Comment: I meant that if you have an array where the user is prompted as to how many spots in the array would they like allocated...like size equals 20. int *array = new int[size]; you set it to 20 but you can add more later if you wish using a dynamic array.

Comment: You cannot change the size of an array once it is allocated. A new array has to be created and the content of the old copied to the new array and the old array deleted (`std::vector` manages this for you).

Comment: exactly. I agree. if you use new and create a dynamic array you can then expand. I understand this.  I just don't understand why it is at all required to put a number in the [ ] to initialize if it is not a const size array.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was  to set the size new int[size]....although I wish that you didn't have to set a size if it is dynamic.

Comment: the real solution is std::vector